# Facebook API and Json with PHP,how to?

Tags: php, json, facebook

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=India&type=post
i am using the above api of Facebook and i am getting following Output

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "501585456_163489377008878",
         "from": {
            "name": "Ian Robinson",
            "id": "501585456"
         },
         "message": "\"Media subdues the public\".  Noam Chomsky still firing http://www.outlookindia.com/article.aspx?267553",
         "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=c6a004d1d5a2ba4cb419ae93c26b2b1f&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphoto.outlookindia.com%2Fimages%2Fgallery%2F20101020%2Fnoam_chomsky_20101101.jpg",
         "link": "http://outlookindia.com/article.aspx?267553",
         "name": "www.outlookindia.com | \u201cMedia Subdues The Public. It\u2019s So In India, Certainly\u201d",
         "caption": "outlookindia.com",
         "description": "Noam Chomsky has a veritable cult following among those who are sceptical about views the liberal media espouses and government propaganda machinery spawns to suit their often overlapping agendas. Compelling is his criticism, breathtaking is his knowledge, persuasive is his voice, and deep runs his ",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
         "type": "link",
         "created_time": "2010-10-24T13:44:01+0000",
         "updated_time": "2010-10-24T13:44:01+0000"
      },
```

How can we convert it into php and get following output

```
Name:Ian Robinson
Description:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

```
$array = json_decode($your_json_data, true);
echo $array['data']['id'];
echo $array['data']['message'];
echo $array['data']['description'];
// and so on
```

---

You can use the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function and treat it like normal array.

> json_decode — Decodes a JSON string

**Example:**

```
 var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Comment: how we will get the file content??

Comment: @Alex Mathew: I have updated the answer but you should be able to decipher that after seeing the exact output of the array with ` var_dump(json_decode($json, true));`